# betapart package installation in Mac

Tags: r, macos

I get the following error message when installing "betapart" package in r (macOS Sierra):

> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘/var/folders/f2/76yg0w2n3s18zqsy8xygr8wr0000gn/T//RtmpvE0c3w/downloaded_packages/betapart’
>   had non-zero exit status

I used the following code:

```
install.packages("https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/betapart", 
                 repos = NULL, type = "source", dependencies = T)
```

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: nein nein nein nein!. Just try `install.packages('betapart')`

Comment: Your line tells R that I want to install this package from its source code, and this documentation page IS the package source code even though it is actually just html code for the webpage. To install from source you need to point to the actual source code as in `install.packages("http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/src/contrib/betapart_1.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source", dependencies = T)`.

Comment: Just tried install.packages('betapart'), got this:  

Warning in install.packages: cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404
Not Found'
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘rcdd’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?

DOES THIS MEAN THAT CAN NOT BE INSTALLED IN MAC? 
@OganM

Comment: did you try saying yes?

Comment: yes, I did @OganM